# Swift sending Multiple Objects to View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, segue

I am trying to send multiple objects from my initial view controller to my `Username VC`. Here is the segue code from my controllers: The issue comes when I add in the code to send the second object, `termreport`. If I delete the `termsM` and the assignment, it send the students as usually, but I also need to send the `termReport` object. How would I fix this?

**ViewControler**:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let students = sender as AnyObject as? [Student]
    else { return }
    guard let termsM = sender as AnyObject as? [TermReport] //How would I send both objects?
    else { return }
    if let secondVC = segue.destination as? UsernameVC {
        secondVC.students = students
        secondVC.userWebView = webView
        secondVC.terms = termsM // not sending
    }
    let gradeResponse = try Parser(innerHTML)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowStudents", sender: gradeResponse.students)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowStudents", sender: gradeResponse.termReports) //how would I send both variables?
```

**UsernameVC**:

```
var terms: [TermReport]!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    print("TERM \(terms[0].grades[3])")//returns found nil optional ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to include all of the variables you want to send to another `ViewController` using a segue into a single object (which can be a collection as well). You either create a custom class/struct that has properties with type `[Student]` and `[TermReport]` or put these into a native collection (Tuple or Dictionary).

Create custom struct:

```
struct TermData {
   var students = [Student]()
   var termReports = [TermReport]()
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let segueData = sender as? TermData
    else { return }
    if let secondVC = segue.destination as? UsernameVC {
        secondVC.students = segueData.students
        secondVC.userWebView = webView
        secondVC.terms = segueData.termReports
        }
}     

let gradeResponse = try Parser(innerHTML)
let termData = TermData(students: gradeResponse.students, termReports: gradeResponse.termReports)
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowStudents", sender: termData)
```

Comment: Very cool way to do that! Worked really well. Thanks. One thing though when you assign let termData = TermData(), you have to instantiate it with the parameters then delete the following two lines. Other than that, it works great.

Comment: Glad you find it useful. Yeah, you're right, I should've declared `termData` as mutable, but in this case you are right, it can be initialised with the values right away, so that's an even cleaner solution.