# How to send multiple variables through segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

How can I send multiple variables through a segue in Swift? The QBBust gets sent over fine and prints on the view controller, but the QBName doesn't get sent over for some reason. Can anyone spot why?

```
        if let send = sender as? Double{
            destination.QBBust = send
        }
        if let sent = sender as? String{
            destination.QBName = sent
        }
    }
}

private var _QBName:String!
var QBName: String{
    get{
        return _QBName
    } set {
        _QBName = newValue
    }
}

private var _QBBust:Double!
var QBBust: Double {
    get {
        return _QBBust
    } set{
        _QBBust = newValue
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let bust = String(Int(_QBBust))
    QBBustLabel.text = "\(bust)%"

    QBNameLabel.text = _QBName
}
```

This next part is in the button function that triggers the segue

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "QBResultVC", sender: QBBust)

performSegue(withIdentifier: "QBResultVC", sender: QBName)
```

Comment: Show the complete function at the top of your code. Show how `QBBust` and `QBName` are declared and initialized (the ones used in the call to `prepareSegue`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in Tiago's answer, you can create a new struct or class which has QBName and QBBust properties. In addition, you can also use tuple in Swift.

This is an example:

in Destination ViewController

declare `var QBInfo:(name: String, bust: Double)?`

and in the button function that triggers the segue

```
let QBInfo = (name: QBName, bust: QBBust)
performSegue(withIdentifier: "QBResultVC", sender: QBBust)
```

then in `prepareForSegue:sender:`method

`destination.QBInfo = QBInfo`

Answer (score 0):

This question is duplicate, but you can create a Struct or new Class, and storage your data how properties and send the 'transport' object in segue.

For detail, look this answser:

[Swift sending Multiple Objects to View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850357/swift-sending-multiple-objects-to-view-controller)